# Is it possible to define override the style of elements from the Manifest?

Tags: android, user-interface, themes

I have an application that has multiple releases for different clients. For each client the theme is different.

It there any way of by changing the application theme in the manifest change all the themes used by TextView, EditText, etc etc on all layouts? 
(without changing the layouts, either by having overriden default styles or defining them on layouts but not having to change it everytime i want to change the client)

**UPDATE - Some options that i also am aware of:**

1. Have custom elements CustomTextView for example that contain inside the logic to decide which theme to use
2. Having a theme.xml per client and define the new Style instead of overriding the standard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a theme.xml file per client... although because of my use of similar names for each style i comment all the files except the one i'm using one the moment.

Not the cleanest solution.. but will do.

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my manifest:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_noteit1"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@style/App_Theme"
    android:name="NoteItApplication" 
    android:debuggable="true">
```

Note the use of `android:theme`.